# Shell Script to trigger procedure with logging

Tags: shell

Here is the shell script which need to trigger a stored procedure and when the record count is 0 then it should capture in the log that 0 duplicate records are found and if it's more than 0 then log with no of records.
Also if there is any sqlerror then it should write the same in the log file and it should send the communication in all scenarios.
We have funct file which has declared with all directories and we are referring here for the log file path directory.
Could you please help me to correct the code logic?

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    . /local/dir1/funct.sh
    sqlplus -s ${ORAUSER}/${ORAPASSWD}@${ORASRVC} <<EOF > $LOG_TEXT 
    set head off
    set serveroutput on
    SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MMDDRRRRHH24MISS') FROM DUAL;
    EOF    
 TIME_STAMP=`cat ${LOG_TEXT}`    
 LOG_FILE_NAME='FileStatus'${TIME_STAMP}'.log'
 LOG_FILE=${LOGFILEDIR}'/FileStatus/'${LOG_FILE_NAME}

write_log "Database Timestamp is $TIME_STAMP"
write_log "Executing FileStatus now..."

sqlplus -s ${ORAUSER}/${ORAPASSWD}@${ORASRVC} <<EOF >> ${LOG_TEXT} 
set feedback off
set heading off
DECLARE
v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
select count(*) INTO v_count from (select col1,col2,count(col3) from Tab1 group by col1,col2 having count(col3)>1);
whenever sqlerror exit -1
whenever oserror exit -1
execute FileStatus;
END;
EOF

if [[ v_count -eq 0 ]] then
        write_log "FileStatus executed successfully."
    write_log "No Duplicate records Found: $LOG_FILE"
         mailx -s "No Duplicate records Found" XXXXX@gmail.com < ${success}
elif [[ "$v_count -gt 0 ]] 
 then
        write_log "FileStatus  executed successfully."
    write_log "Number of duplicate records found::$v_count:$LOG_FILE"
        mailx -s "Number of duplicate records found:$v_count" XXXXX@gmail.com < ${success}
else
        Write_log "FileStatus Failure."
         mailx -s "FileStatus" XXXXX@gmail.com < ${failure}

fi  
cleanup
exit 0;
```

Comment: a few problems I can spot. use https://shellcheck.net to clean up your code. Good luck.

Comment: And, sorry to say, but with limited support to `ksh` (correct me if I'm wrong), you should probably be targeting `#!/bin/bash` as your new shell. Good luck.

Comment: Yes Shelter. i used the shellcheck to cleanup the code but it's not able to identify the funct.sh file where it has DB credentials and log file directory path and getting this error message "not found [No such file or directory]"

Comment: are you sure you really want `. /local/dir1/funct.sh`. I'm not used to seeing systems that have a directory `local` that is placed right in the `root` (i.e. `/`) dir. Maybe you want `.$HOME/local/bin/funct.sh` or similar. Good luck.

Comment: We are using the same dir in other scripts which are reading without issues

Comment: and when you copy/paste to the terminal  and execute `/bin/ls -ld /local/ /local/dir1/funct.sh` what are the results? Good Luck!

Comment: Here is the output --rwxrwxrwx 1 devapp devapp 5859 May 22  2017 /local/dir1/funct.sh

Comment: Even after adding $HOME getting the same error.